# Edit title of popup KML

Tags: google-earth, arcgis-10.8

I want to convert the shapefile to KML. When I open this KML in Google Earth. This popup appears.
[image]

But, I want to change title of this popup to be "Details", like this.

[image]

Comment: It's pretty straight-forward to open the KML in a text editor and modify the balloon contents however you want.  But to full answer this we need to know more about your process.  If it's a one-time change on a small KML, then hand editing the balloons might be easiest.  If this is a single SHP>KML conversion with a large KML, then you can apply a shared balloon style to all the placemarks.  Or if this is one of many files to convert, or a frequently run conversion, then you'll want something that does it during before or during the conversion.  What tool(s) are you using to convert SHP>KML?

Comment: I am using Layer to KML tools, and the size of KML is 191 MB.

Comment: For the Layer to KML tool, check out the documentation. See the top of the "Usage" section: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/layer-to-kml.htm
and this page on how to customize your pop-up balloons: 
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/navigation/configure-pop-ups.htm